# Does the processing time of Airflow dynamic DAGs affect the Executor/Workers or just the Scheduler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, celery, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

I understanding that having heavy processing like database calls to dynamically generate DAGs negatively affects scheduler performance but I can't find clear documentation explaining whether and how it affects the Executor or Workers. I'm trying to find out the root cause of CPUUtilization spikes in my Base Executor.

I see many references to heavy processing in top-level DAG code affecting the scheduler but the only place that suggests it might affect the workers is here: https://www.gotenzo.com/resources/insight/lessons-learned-from-airflow-2-0/ when it mentions that workers

> import the “DagBag”, which involves importing these files, and the
> processing of these DAG files can occur multiple times every second

but I don't fully understand the details of that or see any other mention of this having a notable affect on workers.

My questions to help me better understand:

- What does it mean for a task to "import the DagBag" and how often does the worker need to do that?
- Does it just import the file or run all the top-level code including database calls?
- Why could it "occur multiple times every second"?
- Would the worker actually import *all* DAG files just to run one or does it just import the one? If it just imports the one file, is that really expected to cause performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the worker must also parse the DAG to understand what the task *is*.

Here's an example explaining the rationale from the [Kubernetes executor docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/kubernetes.html):

> Consistent with the regular Airflow architecture, the Workers need access to the DAG files to execute the tasks within those DAGs and interact with the Metadata repository. Also, configuration information specific to the Kubernetes Executor, such as the worker namespace and image information, needs to be specified in the Airflow Configuration file.

To address your questions:

> What does it mean for a task to "import the DagBag" and how often does the worker need to do that?

I believe that no matter the executor, each task will be executed via the cli command `airflow tasks run` (for example, [see this bit in the KubernetesExecutor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/executors/kubernetes_executor_utils.py#L368), which executes the [task_run](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py#L362) function. In order to actually get the task to run, this function needs to first [get the DAG](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/executors/kubernetes_executor_utils.py#L368). It will run once per task.

> Does it just import the file or run all the top-level code including database calls?

It will run all top-level code.

> Why could it "occur multiple times every second"?

Specifically regarding to your question which is quoting another source... I'm not sure. DAG parsing on the scheduler occurs every [min-file-process-interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval). It occurs on the worker once per task instance.

> Would the worker actually import all DAG files just to run one or does it just import the one? If it just imports the one file, is that really expected to cause performance issues?

Just the one. No, it's not *expected* to cause performance issues, but if a DAG is executing costly [top-level DAG code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code), then it could absolutely cause significant performance issues.

Also, "import" might not be the right word here. "Parse" is more accurate, as the files [aren't literally being imported via `from <dags folder> import <dag object>`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/dagbag.py#L176).